# Spring boot maven plugin not terminating forked tomcat process

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I do my development cycle using `mvn clean package spring-boot:run` and it forked a new process to run the tomcat server so you have two: maven process and tomcat process.

The problem is when the maven process is killed, the forked tomcat process isn't dead so I have to go through my task manager each time, search the process and kill it manually.

Is there any setting to disable process forking, or automatically kill the forked process? Tried searching [the plugin manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) but found nothing relevant.

**Edit**: I'm using Spring Boot 1.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: What platform (and Boot version) are you on? The maven process should pass interrupts on to the child process (CTRL-C works for me).

Comment: I'm on windows, I see, this problem might be platform-specific. I found [a workaround which involves using tomcat7-maven-plugin instead of spring-boot-maven-plugin](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/08/22/spring-boot-and-the-embedded-tomcat-container/)

Comment: Why are you using 1.1.1? Please upgrade to the latest (1.1.5 at present) and try again.